# MATLAB compete remove from my laptop

Tags: software-center, uninstall, matlab

How can I remove MATLAB completely which was installed in software center (Ubuntu 18.04 lts) . But I did not install any MATLAB software in my laptop. When I tried to remove MATLAB which was installed from software center but I can't remove it .

Comment: I installed Matlab from Software Centre and I can't uninstall Matlab . So, what can I do for this problem.

Comment: We need to know if you installed a deb or a snap. Go back to Ubuntu Software's entry for MATLAB and tell us the Source. We also need to know the complete error message when MATLAB failed to uninstall.